# the meaning of “public static void(string[] args)”

Tags: java, command-line

being new to java programming and a novice learner, specifically looking at the command

`public static void main(String[] args)`

what does `public static void` mean ? and what are terms like `args` meant to do ?

Comment: Since you're new to Java, you're better off reading some Java tutorials or text first. I'm sure every beginner's text covers this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just FYI, elementary questions that can be answered with some research on your own tend to not be well received here. If you are just starting out with Java, try a basic tutorial like [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). Come back when you have more specific code questions and you will find a better reception. Best of luck.

Comment: You don't need to concern yourself with that line yet, for now think of it as the entry point, magic code that has to be there for the program to work. You'll learn what it means once you've mastered the basics.

Comment: At those pointing to Google and the Java Tutorials - the basic idea of most material you find is "It's magic, you'll figure it out later."

Comment: BTW it should be `String[] args` not `string[] args`. Your code won't compile with `string`. Edited your question. :)

Answer (score 11):

`public` --> access specifier. Any other class can access this method.

`static` --> The method is bound to the class, not to an instance of the class.

`void` --> return type. The method doesn't return *anything*.

`main(String[] args)` --> method name is `main()`. It takes an *array* of *String* 's as argument. The `String[] args` are command line arguments.

Note : The `main()` method defined above is the *entry point* of a program, if you change the signature, then your program might not run.